# Analytic Form of $\int dx \frac{e^{ - m\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + b^2}}e^{ikx }$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, special-functions

Does anyone know how to get an analytic expression of this?

$$\int^L_{-L} dx \frac{e^{- m\sqrt{x^2+b^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + b^2}}e^{ikx} $$ where $k = \dfrac{n\pi}{L}$, $m$, and $b$ are real parameters.

or $$\int^L_{-L} dx \frac{e^{- m|x|}}{\sqrt{x^2 + b^2}} e^{ikx}= \int^L_{0} dx \frac{2\cos{(kx)}e^{- mx}}{\sqrt{x^2 + b^2}}$$ ??

This is a Fourier transform of quasi-one-dimensional Yukawa potential, where b is the fixed width and x is the length between two sources. I feel like this could be related with modified Bessel function of second kind with complex arguments but I am not certain about it.

Comment: What function do the Fourier series coefficients represent?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Yes, it is.